# error al cargar la clase PDO en php uso de namespaces

Tags: php, pdo, class

que tal tengo un problema . Hize un autoloader que es este
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<?php
/**CONSTANTS */
define('SEPARATOR',DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

/** EXEC FUNCTION */
spl_autoload_register('bootstrap');

/**
 * FUNCTIONS
 * @var data = ['file','message','error_create_message']
 * */
function writeLog($data)
{
    if (!file_exists('log')):
        mkdir('log');
    endif;
    date_default_timezone_set("America/Mexico_City");
    setlocale(LC_TIME, "spanish");
    $logFile = fopen($data["file"], 'a') or die("Error creando archivo de LOG");
    fwrite($logFile, "\n".date("d/m/Y H:i:s").' '.$data["message"]) or die($data["error_create_message"]);
    fclose($logFile);
}
/**
 * FUNCTIONS
 * @var bootstrap 
 * autocharge of classes
 * */
function bootstrap($class)
{
    $class = SEPARATOR.str_replace("\\",SEPARATOR,$class).".php";
    $class = substr($class,1);
    
    if (!file_exists($class)):
        $data=[
            "file"=>"log/debug.txt",
            "message"=>" Error al cargar la clase ".$class,
            "error_create_message"=>"No se pudo generar el log"
        ];
        writeLog($data);
        throw new Exception("Error al cargar la clase ".$class);
    else:
        include_once($class);
    endif;
}
```

cada vez que carga la pagina siempre carga el autoloader, pero al querer añadirle una conexión a la DB sale este error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

supongo que es por el autoloader, que esta llamando a esa clase PDO que piensa que esta el mi carpeta system, como le digo que agarre el que esta por defecto en php.

```
<?php
namespace system;

const DB_TYPE="mysql";
const DB_SERVIDOR="172.17.0.1";
const DB_PORT="3306";
const DB_CHARSET="utf8";

class DB{
    // Usuario de la base de datos
    private static $db_usuario="root";
    // Clave de la base de datos
    private static $db_pass="=%Qbwj&-r426XYBP";
    // Nombre del servidor
    private static $db_servidor=DB_SERVIDOR;
    // Nombre de la base de datos
    private static $db_nombre="agis_";
    // Codificación de la base de datos
    private static $db_charset=DB_CHARSET;
    // Puerto de la base de datos
    private static $db_port=DB_PORT;
    // Conexión con la base de datos
    private $conexion;
    
    public function conectar(){
        try{
            $str="mysql:host=".self::$db_servidor.";dbname=".self::$db_nombre;
            $pdo= new PDO($str,self::$db_usuario,self::$db_pass);
            $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTRR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT);
            $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTRR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
            $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTRR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $pdo->exec("SET CHARSET SET".self::$db_charset);
            $pdo->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
            return $pdo;
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            exit("Error: ".$e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la verdad me gustaría que agarrara el PDO no de mi namespace , sino desde el PDO original, alguien me podría apoyar por favor

Comment: ¿Por qué no quitas esto: `namespace system;`?

Comment: Agrega una diagonal invertida porque `PDO` no corresponde al nombre de espacio actual, sino a la raíz: `$pdo = new \PDO(/* Datos de conexión */);`

Comment: muchas gracias lo probaré

Comment: ¿Por qué si las constantes tienen relación o vínculo con la clase donde son usadas las declaras por fuera de la misma?

Comment: buena pregunta y es que lo había sacado por mientras pero en si estan dentro de la clase